# how to disable confirmation dialog when deleting read only or system file by using SHFileOperation / SHFILEOPSTRUCT?

Tags: c++, winapi, recycle-bin

I'm using these flags:

```
SHFILEOPSTRUCTW op;
// ..
op.wFunc = FO_DELETE;
op.fFlags = FOF_ALLOWUNDO | FOF_NORECURSION |
   FOF_RENAMEONCOLLISION | FOF_WANTNUKEWARNING |
   FOF_FILESONLY | FOF_NOCONFIRMATION |
   FOF_NO_CONNECTED_ELEMENTS | FOF_SILENT | FOF_NOERRORUI;
```

And all works ok for files that are not read-only nor system, but when such file is encountered there is a dialog window for user to confirm moving such file to trash. How to disable it ? Must I work around this by first stripping these attributes or is there a setting I do not know of ?

What I need to do is simply to move a file (one by one, I don't need wildcards) to trash. Are there any other api calls that can do this ?

Hidden attribute is not affected by this behavior.

Comment: I don't see that behaviour in my own software.

Comment: I see this in Windows XP SP3.

Comment: [`SHFILEOPSTRUCT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759795.aspx): *"`FOF_WANTNUKEWARNING`: Send a warning if a file is being permanently destroyed during a delete operation rather than recycled. This flag partially overrides `FOF_NOCONFIRMATION`."*